# jqtransform form selector (onchange) problem !

Tags: javascript, forms, events, onchange

I'm styling a form with Jqtransform script.
The form includes a selector which enlist some cities, when i click a one, it should update the selector below it with some locations within that city.

here is the code of the selector

```
<select name="city" id="city" class="wide" onchange="populateDestrict(this)">
```

It was working fine with default style , but after applying JQ, it lost it's functionality

I asked a question before here [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764874/jqtransform-form-events-problem)

and i did as Dormilich did by writing:

```
     $(function() { 
$("form.jqtransform").jqTransform();
$("#city").change(populateDestrict(this)); 
});
```

But it didn't work !

here is also the code of the function if it helps

```
<script language="javascript">
    function populateDestrict(obj){
        var city=obj.value;
            if(city!=""){
                $.post('city_state.php',{ city: city},function(xml){ 
                    $("#state").removeOption(/./);
                    $("district",xml).each(function() {
                    $("#state").addOption($("key",this).text(), $("value",this).text());
                });
            });
            }
    }
</script>
```

Any help people ????????
Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [Polemus's](http://www.polemus.net/2011/06/jqtransform-option-change-not-firing.html) example on how to add the change event handler

Comment: http://www.code-pal.com/the-select-problem-after-using-jqtransform-and-its-solution/

Answer (score 4):

You might have a situation where you have a `<select>` element that has `<option>` elements where the label differs from the value.  For example, you might have a unique ID that corresponds to each city:

```
<form id="formTransform">   
   <div id="boxRelated">
      <select name="city">
         <option value="21">Gotham</option>
         <option value="12">New York City</option>
         <option value="34">Smallville</option>
      </select>
      <div class="clear"></div>   
   </div> 
</form>
```

Simply calling `.text()` on the selected link in the jqTransform list will give you the label, but not the value of the `<option>` element.

To solve this, you can use the index of the parent `<li>` element in the jqtransform list to index into the `<select>` element on  the form:

```
<script> 

   $("#formTransform").jqTransform();

   $("#boxRelated div.jqTransformSelectWrapper ul li a").click(function(){
      var value = $(this).parent().index();
      $("[name=city]").attr('selectedIndex', value);

      // will alert 21, 12, or 34 depending on which one was selected
      alert($("[name=city]").val()); 
      return false; 
   }); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

How to select the display is none, the event will not occur even.
So what you have to do is work on the click event of read that creates jqtransform

```
<form id="formTransform">   
   <div id="boxRelated">
        <select name="select-country">
            <option>Gotham</option>
            <option>New York City</option>
            <option>Smallville</option>
        </select>
     <div class="clear"></div>   
  </div> 
</form>

<script> 

$("#formTransform").jqTransform();

$("#boxRelated div.jqTransformSelectWrapper ul li a").click(function(){
    var value= $("#boxRelated div.jqTransformSelectWrapper span").text()
    alert("Value Selected = "+value);
    return false; //prevent default browser action 
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

May be late but... Faced the same issue recently. and the solution was to use this version of the jqTransform script:

**NOTE:** **1) Open your `jqTransform` file**,  **2)DELETE everything**, **3)COPY** the code bellow **4) PASTE** and **5) SAVE.**

### **VOILA!!**

```
    /*
     *
     * jqTransform
     * by mathieu vilaplana mvilaplana@dfc-e.com
     * Designer ghyslain armand garmand@dfc-e.com
     *
     *
     * Version 1.0 25.09.08
     * Version 1.1 06.08.09
     * Add event click on Checkbox and Radio
     * Auto calculate the size of a select element
     * Can now, disabled the elements
     * Correct bug in ff if click on select (overflow=hidden)
     * No need any more preloading !!
     *
     ******************************************** */

    (function($){
            var defaultOptions = {preloadImg:true};
            var jqTransformImgPreloaded = false;

            var jqTransformPreloadHoverFocusImg = function(strImgUrl) {
                    //guillemets to remove for ie
                    strImgUrl = strImgUrl.replace(/^url\((.*)\)/,'$1').replace(/^\"(.*)\"$/,'$1');
                    var imgHover = new Image();
                    imgHover.src = strImgUrl.replace(/\.([a-zA-Z]*)$/,'-hover.$1');
                    var imgFocus = new Image();
                    imgFocus.src = strImgUrl.replace(/\.([a-zA-Z]*)$/,'-focus.$1');                        
            };


            /***************************
              Labels
            ***************************/
            var jqTransformGetLabel = function(objfield){
                    var selfForm = $(objfield.get(0).form);
                    var oLabel = objfield.next();
                    if(!oLabel.is('label')) {
                            oLabel = objfield.prev();
                            if(oLabel.is('label')){
                                    var inputname = objfield.attr('id');
                                    if(inputname){
                                            oLabel = selfForm.find('label[for="'+inputname+'"]');
                                    }
                            }
                    }
                    if(oLabel.is('label')){return oLabel.css('cursor','pointer');}
                    return false;
            };

            /* Hide all open selects */
            var jqTransformHideSelect = function(oTarget){
                    var ulVisible = $('.jqTransformSelectWrapper ul:visible');
                    ulVisible.each(function(){
                            var oSelect = $(this).parents(".jqTransformSelectWrapper:first").find("select").get(0);
                            //do not hide if click on the label object associated to the select
                            if( !(oTarget && oSelect.oLabel && oSelect.oLabel.get(0) == oTarget.get(0)) ){$(this).hide();}
                    });
            };
            /* Check for an external click */
            var jqTransformCheckExternalClick = function(event) {
                    if ($(event.target).parents('.jqTransformSelectWrapper').length === 0) { jqTransformHideSelect($(event.target)); }
            };

            /* Apply document listener */
            var jqTransformAddDocumentListener = function (){
                    $(document).mousedown(jqTransformCheckExternalClick);
            };     

            /* Add a new handler for the reset action */
            var jqTransformReset = function(f){
                    var sel;
                    $('.jqTransformSelectWrapper select', f).each(function(){sel = (this.selectedIndex<0) ? 0 : this.selectedIndex; $('ul', $(this).parent()).each(function(){$('a:eq('+ sel +')', this).click();});});
                    $('a.jqTransformCheckbox, a.jqTransformRadio', f).removeClass('jqTransformChecked');
                    $('input:checkbox, input:radio', f).each(function(){if(this.checked){$('a', $(this).parent()).addClass('jqTransformChecked');}});
            };

            /***************************
              Buttons
             ***************************/
            $.fn.jqTransInputButton = function(){
                    return this.each(function(){
                            var newBtn = $('<button id="'+ this.id +'" name="'+ this.name +'" type="'+ this.type +'" class="'+ this.className +' jqTransformButton"><span><span>'+ $(this).attr('value') +'</span></span>')
                                    .hover(function(){newBtn.addClass('jqTransformButton_hover');},function(){newBtn.removeClass('jqTransformButton_hover')})
                                    .mousedown(function(){newBtn.addClass('jqTransformButton_click')})
                                    .mouseup(function(){newBtn.removeClass('jqTransformButton_click')})
                            ;
                            $(this).replaceWith(newBtn);
                    });
            };

            /***************************
              Text Fields
             ***************************/
            $.fn.jqTransInputText = function(){
                    return this.each(function(){
                            var $input = $(this);

                            if($input.hasClass('jqtranformdone') || !$input.is('input')) {return;}
                            $input.addClass('jqtranformdone');

                            var oLabel = jqTransformGetLabel($(this));
                            oLabel && oLabel.bind('click',function(){$input.focus();});

                            var inputSize=$input.width();
                            if($input.attr('size')){
                                    inputSize = $input.attr('size')*10;
                                    $input.css('width',inputSize);
                            }

                            $input.addClass("jqTransformInput").wrap('<div class="jqTransformInputWrapper"><div class="jqTransformInputInner"><div></div></div></div>');
                            var $wrapper = $input.parent().parent().parent();
                            $wrapper.css("width", inputSize+10);
                            $input
                                    .focus(function(){$wrapper.addClass("jqTransformInputWrapper_focus");})
                                    .blur(function(){$wrapper.removeClass("jqTransformInputWrapper_focus");})
                                    .hover(function(){$wrapper.addClass("jqTransformInputWrapper_hover");},function(){$wrapper.removeClass("jqTransformInputWrapper_hover");})
                            ;

                            /* If this is safari we need to add an extra class */
                            $.browser.safari && $wrapper.addClass('jqTransformSafari');
                            $.browser.safari && $input.css('width',$wrapper.width()+16);
                            this.wrapper = $wrapper;

                    });
            };

            /***************************
              Check Boxes
             ***************************/  
            $.fn.jqTransCheckBox = function(){
                    return this.each(function(){
                            if($(this).hasClass('jqTransformHidden')) {return;}

                            var $input = $(this);
                            var inputSelf = this;

                            //set the click on the label
                            var oLabel=jqTransformGetLabel($input);
                            oLabel && oLabel.click(function(){aLink.trigger('click');});

                            var aLink = $('<a href="#" class="jqTransformCheckbox"></a>');
                            //wrap and add the link
                            $input.addClass('jqTransformHidden').wrap('<span class="jqTransformCheckboxWrapper"></span>').parent().prepend(aLink);
                            //on change, change the class of the link
                            $input.change(function(){
                                    this.checked && aLink.addClass('jqTransformChecked') || aLink.removeClass('jqTransformChecked');
                                    return true;
                            });
                            // Click Handler, trigger the click and change event on the input
                            aLink.click(function(){
                                    //do nothing if the original input is disabled
                                    if($input.attr('disabled')){return false;}
                                    //trigger the envents on the input object
                                    $input.trigger('click').trigger("change");     
                                    return false;
                            });

                            // set the default state
                            this.checked && aLink.addClass('jqTransformChecked');          
                    });
            };
            /***************************
              Radio Buttons
             ***************************/  
            $.fn.jqTransRadio = function(){
                    return this.each(function(){
                            if($(this).hasClass('jqTransformHidden')) {return;}

                            var $input = $(this);
                            var inputSelf = this;

                            oLabel = jqTransformGetLabel($input);
                            oLabel && oLabel.click(function(){aLink.trigger('click');});

                            var aLink = $('<a href="#" class="jqTransformRadio" rel="'+ this.name +'"></a>');
                            $input.addClass('jqTransformHidden').wrap('<span class="jqTransformRadioWrapper"></span>').parent().prepend(aLink);

                            $input.change(function(){
                                    inputSelf.checked && aLink.addClass('jqTransformChecked') || aLink.removeClass('jqTransformChecked');
                                    return true;
                            });
                            // Click Handler
                            aLink.click(function(){
                                    if($input.attr('disabled')){return false;}
                                    $input.trigger('click').trigger('change');

                                    // uncheck all others of same name input radio elements
                                    $('input[name="'+$input.attr('name')+'"]',inputSelf.form).not($input).each(function(){
                                            $(this).attr('type')=='radio' && $(this).trigger('change');
                                    });

                                    return false;                                  
                            });
                            // set the default state
                            inputSelf.checked && aLink.addClass('jqTransformChecked');
                    });
            };

            /***************************
              TextArea
             ***************************/  
            $.fn.jqTransTextarea = function(){
                    return this.each(function(){
                            var textarea = $(this);

                            if(textarea.hasClass('jqtransformdone')) {return;}
                            textarea.addClass('jqtransformdone');

                            oLabel = jqTransformGetLabel(textarea);
                            oLabel && oLabel.click(function(){textarea.focus();});

                            var strTable = '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="jqTransformTextarea">';
                            strTable +='<tr><td id="jqTransformTextarea-tl"></td><td id="jqTransformTextarea-tm"></td><td id="jqTransformTextarea-tr"></td></tr>';
                            strTable +='<tr><td id="jqTransformTextarea-ml">&nbsp;</td><td id="jqTransformTextarea-mm"><div></div></td><td id="jqTransformTextarea-mr">&nbsp;</td></tr>';  
                            strTable +='<tr><td id="jqTransformTextarea-bl"></td><td id="jqTransformTextarea-bm"></td><td id="jqTransformTextarea-br"></td></tr>';
                            strTable +='</table>';                                 
                            var oTable = $(strTable)
                                            .insertAfter(textarea)
                                            .hover(function(){
                                                    !oTable.hasClass('jqTransformTextarea-focus') && oTable.addClass('jqTransformTextarea-hover');
                                            },function(){
                                                    oTable.removeClass('jqTransformTextarea-hover');                                       
                                            })
                                    ;

                            textarea
                                    .focus(function(){oTable.removeClass('jqTransformTextarea-hover').addClass('jqTransformTextarea-focus');})
                                    .blur(function(){oTable.removeClass('jqTransformTextarea-focus');})
                                    .appendTo($('#jqTransformTextarea-mm div',oTable))
                            ;
                            this.oTable = oTable;
                            if($.browser.safari){
                                    $('#jqTransformTextarea-mm',oTable)
                                            .addClass('jqTransformSafariTextarea')
                                            .find('div')
                                                    .css('height',textarea.height())
                                                    .css('width',textarea.width())
                                    ;
                            }
                    });
            };

            /***************************
              Select
             ***************************/  
            $.fn.jqTransSelect = function(){
                    return this.each(function(index){
                            var $select = $(this);

                            if($select.hasClass('jqTransformHidden')) {return;}
                            if($select.attr('multiple')) {return;}

                            var oLabel  =  jqTransformGetLabel($select);
                            /* First thing we do is Wrap it */
                            var $wrapper = $select
                                    .addClass('jqTransformHidden')
                                    .wrap('<div class="jqTransformSelectWrapper"></div>')
                                    .parent()
                                    .css({zIndex: 10-index})
                            ;

                            /* Now add the html for the select */
                            $wrapper.prepend('<div><span></span><a href="#" class="jqTransformSelectOpen"></a></div><ul></ul>');
                            var $ul = $('ul', $wrapper).css('width',$select.width()).hide();
                            /* Now we add the options */
                            $('option', this).each(function(i){
                                    var oLi = $('<li><a href="#" index="'+ i +'">'+ $(this).html() +'</a></li>');
                                    $ul.append(oLi);
                            });

                            /* Add click handler to the a */
                            $ul.find('a').click(function(){
                                            $('a.selected', $wrapper).removeClass('selected');
                                            $(this).addClass('selected');  
                                            /* Fire the onchange event */
                                            //if ($select[0].selectedIndex != $(this).attr('index') && $select[0].onchange) { $select[0].selectedIndex = $(this).attr('index'); $select[0].onchange(); }
                                            if ($select[0].selectedIndex != $(this).attr('index')) { $select[0].selectedIndex = $(this).attr('index'); $select.change(); }

                                    //Redundent code
                                            //$select[0].selectedIndex = $(this).attr('index');
                                            $('span:eq(0)', $wrapper).html($(this).html());
                                            $ul.hide();
                                            return false;
                            });
                            /* Set the default */
                            $('a:eq('+ this.selectedIndex +')', $ul).click();
                            $('span:first', $wrapper).click(function(){$("a.jqTransformSelectOpen",$wrapper).trigger('click');});
                            oLabel && oLabel.click(function(){$("a.jqTransformSelectOpen",$wrapper).trigger('click');});
                            this.oLabel = oLabel;

                            /* Apply the click handler to the Open */
                            var oLinkOpen = $('a.jqTransformSelectOpen', $wrapper)
                                    .click(function(){
                                            //Check if box is already open to still allow toggle, but close all other selects
                                            if( $ul.css('display') == 'none' ) {jqTransformHideSelect();}
                                            if($select.attr('disabled')){return false;}

                                            $ul.slideToggle('fast', function(){                                    
                                                    var offSet = ($('a.selected', $ul).offset().top - $ul.offset().top);
                                                    $ul.animate({scrollTop: offSet});
                                            });
                                            return false;
                                    })
                            ;

                            // Set the new width
                            var iSelectWidth = $select.outerWidth();
                            var oSpan = $('span:first',$wrapper);
                            var newWidth = (iSelectWidth > oSpan.innerWidth())?iSelectWidth+oLinkOpen.outerWidth():$wrapper.width();
                            $wrapper.css('width',newWidth);
                            $ul.css('width',newWidth-2);
                            oSpan.css({width:iSelectWidth});

                            // Calculate the height if necessary, less elements that the default height
                            //show the ul to calculate the block, if ul is not displayed li height value is 0
                            $ul.css({display:'block',visibility:'hidden'});
                            var iSelectHeight = ($('li',$ul).length)*($('li:first',$ul).height());//+1 else bug ff
                            (iSelectHeight < $ul.height()) && $ul.css({height:iSelectHeight,'overflow':'hidden'});//hidden else bug with ff
                            $ul.css({display:'none',visibility:'visible'});

                    });
            };
            $.fn.jqTransform = function(options){
                    var opt = $.extend({},defaultOptions,options);

                    /* each form */
                     return this.each(function(){
                            var selfForm = $(this);
                            if(selfForm.hasClass('jqtransformdone')) {return;}
                            selfForm.addClass('jqtransformdone');

                            $('input:submit, input:reset, input[type="button"]', this).jqTransInputButton();                       
                            $('input:text, input:password', this).jqTransInputText();                      
                            $('input:checkbox', this).jqTransCheckBox();
                            $('input:radio', this).jqTransRadio();
                            $('textarea', this).jqTransTextarea();

                            if( $('select', this).jqTransSelect().length > 0 ){jqTransformAddDocumentListener();}
                            selfForm.bind('reset',function(){var action = function(){jqTransformReset(this);}; window.setTimeout(action, 10);});

                            //preloading dont needed anymore since normal, focus and hover image are the same one
                            /*if(opt.preloadImg && !jqTransformImgPreloaded){
                                    jqTransformImgPreloaded = true;
                                    var oInputText = $('input:text:first', selfForm);
                                    if(oInputText.length > 0){
                                            //pour ie on eleve les ""
                                            var strWrapperImgUrl = oInputText.get(0).wrapper.css('background-image');
                                            jqTransformPreloadHoverFocusImg(strWrapperImgUrl);                                     
                                            var strInnerImgUrl = $('div.jqTransformInputInner',$(oInputText.get(0).wrapper)).css('background-image');
                                            jqTransformPreloadHoverFocusImg(strInnerImgUrl);
                                    }

                                    var oTextarea = $('textarea',selfForm);
                                    if(oTextarea.length > 0){
                                            var oTable = oTextarea.get(0).oTable;
                                            $('td',oTable).each(function(){
                                                    var strImgBack = $(this).css('background-image');
                                                    jqTransformPreloadHoverFocusImg(strImgBack);
                                            });
                                    }
                            }*/


                    }); /* End Form each */

            };/* End the Plugin */

})(jQuery);
```

You could also get the same here: http://pastebin.com/Q1pYMKZ2

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy way to get the selected value from a transformed select drop down:

```
$("#boxRelated div.jqTransformSelectWrapper ul li a").click(function(){

    var SelectedVal = $("#boxRelated option:selected").val();

    console.log(SelectedVal);

})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#city").change(populateDestrict);
```

In JavaScript (unlike to the HTML event attributes) you have to assign a function reference. using parentheses with that will cause the function’s return value to be assigned instead of the function (IE does its own thing of course).

you also have to edit your function accordingly—simply use `this` instead of `obj`. as the first and only parameter the event object will be passed (not in IE, though, but jQuery takes care of that)

Comment: thanks a lot for you effort. 
really appreciated.
I did as you said : putting that code - nothing changed
also changing obj with this in the function code itself- also nothing changes !
I wanted also to say that when i select the city, the search shows results for that city, but the selector below doesn't update according to it !
It just remains including locations for the first one (not the selected city)

also the form is functioning normally without jqtransform,
so I don't think the main function code is wrong.

thanks a lot , and waiting for your reply

Comment: does your function start like this?
    function populateDestrict(){
        var city=this.value;

Comment: I know this is dead.. but its the same thing to do `.change(populateDestrict)` as `.change(function(){ populateDestrict(); })`